# Does Embeddings and Vector Databases solve the need of having longer context windows?

Tags: transformer, large-language-models

I am learning to use the OpenAI API to build LLM-based agents. I recently came across the concept of vector databases, which use embeddings to convert text into vectors and store them in a database for easy retrieval. This technique has been shown to be very useful for long-memory applications.

My question is whether it is necessary to have longer context windows in models that use the embedding + database technique. I know that there has been some research on expanding the context window of transformers, such as the [Scaling Transformer to 1M tokens and beyond with RMT](https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.11062) paper and [Microsoft's LongNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.02486) architecture. At what point does increasing the context window lead to better performance than using a vector database approach? Are there any examples or experiments that demonstrate this?